# Nant does not see reference

Tags: c#, nant

I want to kill all IE instances by nant script with c# code:

```
<target name="clean">  
   <script language="C#" prefix="Cleaning">          
          <references>
              <include name="System.Diagnostics.dll" />
          </references>
                <imports>
                    <import namespace="System.Diagnostics" />
                </imports>
          <code>
            <![CDATA[

              [Function("Delete")]
              public static void KillIe() 
              {                     

                foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore"))
                {
                  process.Kill();
                }         

              }
            ]]>
          </code>
      </script>
 <echo message="Calling function: ${Cleaning::KillIe()}"/> 
  </target>    
</project>
```

When I execute this script I get the following error:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Process' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'System.Diagnostics' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I ended up adding the following reference to the NAnt code:

```
<script ... >
  <references>
    <include name="System.dll"/>
    ...
  </references>
  <code>
    ...
  </code>
</script>
```

You should add `System.dll` explicitly - it is not in the [list of assemblies included by default](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/script.html).

Comment: And, more specifically, they should use the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) to learn what *assembly* the class they wish to use is contained in. Namespace != Assembly.